# Change index in array.map

Tags: javascript

I have a variable of the form:

```
var data=[
{
    start:22,
    end: 8
},
{
    start:60,
    end: 43       
},
{
    start: 35,
    end: 55
},
{
    start:25,
    end:40
}
];
```

I want to map it to look like this

```
var newData = { 22:8, 60:43, 35:55, 25:40};
```

Is this possible? I mainly just want to use the start numbers as a key to access the end numbers without using search. I have tried to do this:

```
 var mapData = data.map(function(data){
  var x = {};
  x[data.start]=data.end;
  return x;
});
```

but it gives:
    0
:
{22: 8}
1
:
{60: 43}
2
:
{35: 55}
3
:
{25: 40}
which means i have to use 0, 1,2, 3 as indices.

Comment: please add a valid result.

Comment: `newData` is not a valid object.

Comment: Did you mean `{ 22:8, 60:43, 35:55, 25:40 }`?

Comment: impossible you cant write like "{8}"

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes I meant that, i'll edit to say this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does not work in this case, because without post processing, you get a single array with objects. You need to combine all objects into a single object.

With [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), you get a single array with all properties from the objects in the array.

```js
var data = [{ start: 22, end: 8 }, { start: 60, end: 43 }, { start: 35, end: 55 }, { start: 25, end: 40 }],
    result = Object.assign(...data.map(({ start, end }) => ({ [start]: end })));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nina. I was not aware of the spread syntax, since I'm still a beginner to javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You can use array.reduce:

```js
var data=[
{
    start:22,
    end: 8
},
{
    start:60,
    end: 43       
},
{
    start: 35,
    end: 55
},
{
    start:25,
    end:40
}
];

var res = data.reduce((m, o) => { 
  m[o.start] = o.end; 
  return m;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of these methods.